# TypeScript: typing an httprequest with diverse return types

Tags: typescript, http, es6-promise

I'm fairly familiar with Javascript, but having some issues recreating some of the patterns I use in TypeScript, because I'm not sure how to type functions that could have diverse JSON fields. For example, I was trying to write a simple http request function that I could use:

```
async function requestTest (options: https.RequestOptions) {
    const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                if (d.status == 200) {
                    resolve(d)
                }
                reject('failed')
            })
        })
    return await prom
```

However, if I actually want to use this function, say query a database and get back a result where the "data" field on the response will contain data of a known structure that I have an interface declared for:

```
const getData = (opts): ISomeStructure => {
    return requestTest(opts)
}
```

I get an error of the type:

`Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ISomeStructure'.`

How do I declare the types in such a way as to tell typescript that in this case, I am expecting the http response to have a key that contains an `ISomeStructure` JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code, one related to async code, the other related to types.

The async issue is that you return `requestTest(opts)` while you declare that your function will return `ISomeStructure`. Since `requestTest` retruns a `Promise` you should return a `Promis<ISomeStructure>` from `getData`, since the data returned by `requestTest` will not be immediately available to return directly.

The second problem is that you should allow the return type of the request to be specified as a type parameter on `requestTest` that way your function can be used for any returned type.

```
function requestTest<T>(options: https.RequestOptions) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                if (d.status == 200) {
                    resolve(d)
                }
                reject('failed')
            })
        })
    });
}

const getData = (opts: https.RequestOptions): Promise<ISomeStructure> => {
    return requestTest<ISomeStructure>(opts)
}
```